# Upgrading to 19.10 Eoan Ermine from 19.04

Tags: upgrade, ubuntu-studio

I'm attempting to upgrade to 19.10 from the 18.04 LTS but have encountered some blockages. I followed the instruction to change the line in release-upgrades then on trying got a message in the console that "Upgrades to the development release are only available from the latest supported release."

I then used the upgrade-manager (Alt F2), followed the instructions and got upgraded to 19.04. However a second attempt with the result shown in this image, confirmed that there is a 19.10 upgrade but I have no luck installing it. [Photo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dxg1.png)

Attempts via the terminal:

"mark@mark:~$ lsb_release -a
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 19.04
Release:    19.04
Codename:   disco
mark@mark:~$ sudo do-release-upgrade -d
[sudo] password for mark:
 
Checking for a new Ubuntu release
Upgrades to the development release are only
 
available from the latest supported release."

I'd appreciate any help in getting over this hump.

Thanks.

Comment: Hint: What do you expect the `-d` flag to do?

Comment: I'm following the instructions at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/EoanErmine/ReleaseNotes/UbuntuStudio

Comment: That instruction was mistaken - it should not have included the `-d` flag. Thank you for the link, I have corrected the mistake. You have contributed to a better Ubuntu!

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using apt update rather than apt-get update. Apt showed that a Calf-plugin package needed to be upgraded. Apt-get did not show that information. Installing the calf-plugin update solved the problem.

Comment: Correlation, not the real cause. The real cause of the problem in your original question was use of the '-d' flag, which tells the system to upgrade to the *development* release (currently 20.04), not the *most recent* release (19.10).

Comment: Aah. Thanks for that info. However, no option was successful--with -d or without--until I followed the instruction in the console with regards updating Calf-plugin. So yes, on the one hand, with -d was attempting  to upgrade to the development release, while on the other, without that flag there was another obstacle to the upgrade. Thanks.

Comment: So you had two separate, unrelated issues to correct. Needed to make that clear for future readers. Your specific pair of issues is unlikely to affect most other users.

Comment: ...Also, as per the image in the original post, the Software Updater route was not successful since it showed that 19.10 (Ubuntu Studio/Ubuntu) was available but I got no feedback on why the Upgrade command using the button didn't give the desired result. apt-get did not provide the detailed comments that apt did. https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dxg1.png